# Android TV box MediaPlayer info/warning (8004, 0), error (1, -33554485)

Tags: android, media-player

I am working on a project that plays media using mediaplayer.
I was testing the application and I noticed that the app had frozen.
When I reviewed the logs I saw these lines that maybe clue for the reason.

```
08-21 09:56:57.737  1512  1551 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (8004, 0)
08-21 09:56:57.737  1512  1524 E MediaPlayer: error (1, -33554485)
```

This happened when testing with huge playlist.
That is very sad that there is no enough detailed documentation about these errors.

Since the project is huge because it has a manual crossfade functionality I am not able to share code. I do not have a comprehensive knowledge about the program flow. I just want to have an information about these warnings and errors.

**UPDATE:** Since I could not figure out the reason of the error, I just skipped the song so that the media player won't stop. To do that I checked if media player is not playing after the error is occurred the media player needs to skip to the next song.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder if you could use an exoplayer? more advanced than mediaplayer.

Comment: You think that it will prevent those problems? I do not want to change the code too much since it is a little bit complicated.

Comment: While the 3rd party is a library, it continues to be developed by forking by google. As a matter of fact, the mediaplayer is free of problems and offers more features. Still, I don't know if it's a quick solution. Keep it in mind if you can't find another solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advices. I will keep it in my mind in case I can not find any other solution.